# javascript function doesn't finish running

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following JQuery/JS set up to open/close a menu:

```
$('button.leftNav-dropDownButton').toggle(function () {
            $(this).addClass('dropDownActive');
            ...do stuff
        },
        function () {
            alert("Button has been clicked");
            $(this).removeClass('dropDownActive');
            ...do other stuff
        }
    );
```

The function works fine when adding the dropDownActive class, which tells the CSS to display my menu, but when I click the button again, the alert pops up, so I know that the function is being called, but nothing goes away unless you click on the very outside of the button. Here is what the button looks like when active:

```
<button class="leftNav-dropDownButton hide-for-print dropDownActive">
    <span class="icon-reorder "></span>      //little menu icon
    <span class="icon-folder-arrow"></span> //arrow under button that points
                                            //from menu to button
</button>
```

And here is what it looks like when inactive:

```
<button class="leftNav-dropDownButton hide-for-print">
    <span class="icon-reorder "></span>
</button>
```

I've tried removing the icon-folder-arrow, but that didn't help.

Comment: Passing two functions to .toggle() as separate params seems weird. See: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: My initial thought is to follow the api for .toggle() and pass 1 function as a parameter and inside that function use an if to check if the dropdown is open or closed. Then the branches would close the dropdown (if it was open) or vice versa.

Comment: #sidenav {
    margin: -9999px;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 40px;
    max-height: 85%;
    left: 3px;
    height: auto !important;
    position: relative;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 20px #111;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 20px #111;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 20px #111;
    border-radius: 0px !important;
  }
  #sidenav .LeftContentNav-clientinfo {
    display: none;
  }
  #sidenav .no-sidenav {
    display: none;
  }

Comment: paste your code on jsfiddle